# PowerBI - API returns empty JSON

Tags: json, powerbi, jira, dax

i need your support please for this ...

Actually i'm using Power BI to analyse datas coming from JIRA.
I built filters in JIRA and i'm getting the datas from those filters using APIs / JSON files.

It works fine when the JSON contains data : i'll do this to transform the data :

**Connect the source**

```
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://jira.xxx.com/jra/rest/api/2/search?startIndex=0&jql=filter=154325&maxResults=1000")),
issues = Source[issues],
```

**Transform the data**

```
#"Converti en table" = Table.FromList(issues, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Column1 développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converti en table", "Column1", {"key", "fields"}, {"key", "fields"}),
#"Colonnes renommées" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Column1 développé",{{"key", "jira num"}}),
#"fields développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Colonnes renommées", "fields", {"issuetype", "project", "priority", "labels", "issuelinks", "status", "components", "summary"}, {"issuetype", "project", "priority", "labels", "issuelinks", "status", "components", "summary"}),
#"issuetype développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"fields développé", "issuetype", {"name"}, {"name"}),
#"Colonnes renommées1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"issuetype développé",{{"name", "type"}}),
#"project développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Colonnes renommées1", "project", {"name"}, {"name"}),
#"Colonnes renommées2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"project développé",{{"name", "project"}}),
#"priority développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Colonnes renommées2", "priority", {"name"}, {"name"}),
#"Colonnes renommées3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"priority développé",{{"name", "severity"}}),
#"labels développé" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Colonnes renommées3", "labels"),
#"issuelinks développé" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"labels développé", "issuelinks"),
#"issuelinks développé2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"issuelinks développé", "issuelinks", {"type", "inwardIssue", "outwardIssue"}, {"type.1", "inwardIssue", "outwardIssue"}),
#"type.1 développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"issuelinks développé2", "type.1", {"inward", "outward"}, {"inward", "outward"}),
#"inwardIssue développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"type.1 développé", "inwardIssue", {"key"}, {"key"}),
#"Colonnes renommées4" = Table.RenameColumns(#"inwardIssue développé",{{"key", "split from"}}),
#"outwardIssue développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Colonnes renommées4", "outwardIssue", {"key"}, {"key"}),
#"Colonnes renommées5" = Table.RenameColumns(#"outwardIssue développé",{{"key", "split to"}}),
#"status développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Colonnes renommées5", "status", {"name"}, {"name"}),
#"Colonnes renommées6" = Table.RenameColumns(#"status développé",{{"name", "status"}}),
#"components développé" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Colonnes renommées6", "components"),
#"components développé1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"components développé", "components", {"name"}, {"name"}),
#"Colonnes renommées7" = Table.RenameColumns(#"components développé1",{{"name", "component"}}),
#"Colonnes permutées" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Colonnes renommées7",{"jira num", "type", "project", "severity", "labels", "inward", "split from", "outward", "split to", "status", "component", "summary"}),
#"Colonnes renommées8" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Colonnes permutées",{{"split from", "inwardissue"}, {"split to", "outwardissue"}}),
#"Personnalisée ajoutée" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes renommées8", "URL JIRA", each Text.Combine({"https://jira.xxx.com/jra/browse/",[jira num]},"")),
#"Lignes filtrées" = Table.SelectRows(#"Personnalisée ajoutée", each ([labels] = "YYY"))
in
    #"Lignes filtrées"
```

But when the JSON is empty because the JIRA filter is empty, i get this error:
`Expression.Error : the name « Column1 développé » is unknown`

I think it comes from this line :

```
#"Column1 développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converti en table", "Column1", {"key", "fields"}, {"key", "fields"}),
```

and i fully understand the error base on the fact that the JOSN is empty.

My point is : i wanna consider enmpty JSON files in my algorithm and return an empty table with the correct columns.

How can i do this ?

I suppose i can check if the variable "issues" contains something or not ?
If yes, just do as described above
If not, generate an empty table with all needed columns and return it without executing the transform data algorithm.

thank you for you support

Comment: can you provide an JSON example of what JIRA returns when it is empty? does it contain anything? you rely on JIRA to give you the column names, and if there is nothing in the JSON you need to manually add those columns

Comment: ty for your reply.
there's no file when there's no data.
You are right on the fact that i must built manually an empty table with the right columns but i don't know how i can do it using DAX. 

I think i would need some help to add to my algorithm :
- Checking if the JSON is empty or not ? 
- if not, generating the empty table and return it 

ty

Answer (score 0):

so i would create 3 Queries:
**First query** creates and empty table with the manually define column names:

```
let
     Source = #table({"first","second","third"}, {{"","",""}})
in
     Source
```

**Second query** is to load the datasource until the point you get the exact same column names. something like this i would guess:

```
let
     Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://jira.xxx.com/jra/rest/api/2/search?startIndex=0&jql=filter=154325&maxResults=1000")),
     issues = Source[issues],
     #"Converti en table" = Table.FromList(issues, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in 
     #"Converti en table"
```

**Third query** Append the two first queries into a new query (see under Home->Combine->Append Queries).
**Note** that the column names has to match.
After that you can proceed to do your transformation and you will get something like:

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({Query1, Query2}),
    #"Column1 développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Source, "Column1", {"key", "fields"}, {"key", "fields"}),
    #"Colonnes renommées" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Column1 développé",{{"key", "jira num"}}),
    #"fields développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Colonnes renommées", "fields", {"issuetype", "project", "priority", "labels", "issuelinks", "status", "components", "summary"}, {"issuetype", "project", "priority", "labels", "issuelinks", "status", "components", "summary"}),
    #"issuetype développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"fields développé", "issuetype", {"name"}, {"name"}),
    .
    .
    .
    #"Lignes filtrées" = Table.SelectRows(#"Personnalisée ajoutée", each ([labels] = "YYY"))
in
    #"Lignes filtrées"
```

Answer (score 0):

ty very much for this suggestion. I understand the idea. What i am afraid of is the capability to recreate the same original table structure which is very complexe.

Is it not possible to create a table with only th final structure that i know ?

The news is that i finally have an empty file in first query so that i can check the total of result.

I've tried this ;

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://jira.xxx.com/jra/rest/api/2/search?startIndex=0&jql=filter=154324&maxResults=1000")),
    issues = Source[issues],
    total = Source[total],
    mytable = #table({"first","second","third"}, {{"","",""}}),
    
    result = if(total <> 0) then 
    {
        #"Converti en table" = Table.FromList(issues, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
        #"Column1 développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converti en table", "Column1", {"key", "fields"}, {"key", "fields"}),
        #"Colonnes renommées" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Column1 développé",{{"key", "jira num"}}),
        #"fields développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Colonnes renommées", "fields", {"issuetype", "project", "priority", "labels", "issuelinks", "status", "components", "summary"}, {"issuetype", "project", "priority", "labels", "issuelinks", "status", "components", "summary"}),
        #"issuetype développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"fields développé", "issuetype", {"name"}, {"name"}),
        #"Colonnes renommées1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"issuetype développé",{{"name", "type"}}),
        #"project développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Colonnes renommées1", "project", {"name"}, {"name"}),
        #"Colonnes renommées2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"project développé",{{"name", "project"}}),
        #"priority développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Colonnes renommées2", "priority", {"name"}, {"name"}),
        #"Colonnes renommées3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"priority développé",{{"name", "severity"}}),
        #"labels développé" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Colonnes renommées3", "labels"),
        #"issuelinks développé" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"labels développé", "issuelinks"),
        #"issuelinks développé2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"issuelinks développé", "issuelinks", {"type", "inwardIssue", "outwardIssue"}, {"type.1", "inwardIssue", "outwardIssue"}),
        #"type.1 développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"issuelinks développé2", "type.1", {"inward", "outward"}, {"inward", "outward"}),
        #"inwardIssue développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"type.1 développé", "inwardIssue", {"key"}, {"key"}),
        #"Colonnes renommées4" = Table.RenameColumns(#"inwardIssue développé",{{"key", "split from"}}),
        #"outwardIssue développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Colonnes renommées4", "outwardIssue", {"key"}, {"key"}),
        #"Colonnes renommées5" = Table.RenameColumns(#"outwardIssue développé",{{"key", "split to"}}),
        #"status développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Colonnes renommées5", "status", {"name"}, {"name"}),
        #"Colonnes renommées6" = Table.RenameColumns(#"status développé",{{"name", "status"}}),
        #"components développé" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Colonnes renommées6", "components"),
        #"components développé1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"components développé", "components", {"name"}, {"name"}),
        #"Colonnes renommées7" = Table.RenameColumns(#"components développé1",{{"name", "component"}}),
        #"Colonnes permutées" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Colonnes renommées7",{"jira num", "type", "project", "severity", "labels", "inward", "split from", "outward", "split to", "status", "component", "summary"}),
        #"Colonnes renommées8" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Colonnes permutées",{{"split from", "inwardissue"}, {"split to", "outwardissue"}}),
        #"Personnalisée ajoutée" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes renommées8", "URL JIRA", each Text.Combine({"https://jira.xxx.com/jra/browse/",[jira num]},"")),
        #"Lignes filtrées" = Table.SelectRows(#"Personnalisée ajoutée", each ([labels] = "FilRougeMVP0.5"))
    }
    else
        total = 0
in
    if(total <> 0) 
    then #"Lignes filtrées"
    else mytable
```

But i have an error : Expression.Error : Le nom « Converti en table » is unknwon

I'm convinced i'm not far from the target but i need a little more help :)

ty very much for that.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is the content of the file with no result :

```
{"startAt":0,"maxResults":1000,"total":0,"issues":[]}
```